# Draw chart.js created by ckeditor plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, chart.js

I use ckeditor and create chart with chartjs plugin:

```
<div class="chartjs" data-chart="doughnut" data-chart-height="300"
data-chart-value="[{"value":70,"label":"A"},{"value":50,"label":"B"}]"></div>
```

BUT I don't know how can draw chart when html page loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add these lines to head and solve my problem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ckeditor/plugins/chart/lib/chart.css">
<script src="ckeditor/plugins/chart/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="ckeditor/plugins/chart/widget2chart.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `canvas` for your chart container

```
<canvas id="chartjs" width='300' height='300'></canvas>
```

And then run this javascript, passing your parameters as follows:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chartjs");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ["A", "B"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [70, 50],
            backgroundColor: ['red', 'pink']
        }]
    },
});
```

[See working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/dL5kc2qx/)

Comment: thank u, but this is handy and not compatible with ckeditor plugin.